# jQuery is not, not working for me

Tags: jquery

Should the following condition change the link, if either Dog or Cat is found in a list?

```
var mtarget = $('#jqwlclink'); //the target link that will change only if dog or cat exist for mlink element.


if (mtarget.length) {

$("#profile-bottom .pleft .mlink").each(function() {
      if (!$(this).is(':contains("Dog"),:contains("Cat")')) {
        mtarget.attr("href", "http://different-page/");
      }
    });

}
```

for some reason this it is still changing the href of my target, even though Dog and Cat are found in `$(this)`.

My HTML looks like this..

```
<div class="pleft">
  <span class="ph3">My Account</span>
  <a class="mlink dots" href="/dog">Item One - Dog</a>
  <a class="mlink dots" href="/cat">Item Two - Cat</a>
</div>
```

The HTML of the target that will potentially change...

```
<a id="jqwlclink" href="/initial-page/">Status</a>
```

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: How do you want to alter the page? Should the words (`"cat"` or `"dog"`) occur in the `href` or in the text? Or both?

Comment: Do you know if the `is` part is working correctly?  i.e. does `$(this).is(':contains("Dog"),:contains("Cat")')` return true for your case?

Comment: "*[It should] alter the href based on existence of either text value showing up*" - how?

Comment: Yes. I understand the `href` should change. But how should the presence of `"dog"` affect the `href`? How should the presence of `"cat"` affect the `href`? "Affect it" it *how*; what differences should be made? What, exactly, do you want to happen to the `href` based upon the presence of these words?

Comment: It helps a little, but the way you're approaching the problem the `href` of `mtarget` will be changed repeatedly, first to the `dog` version, then to the `cat` version. Should this change take place on page-load or on clicking the link?

Comment: David, I apologized if I complicated the original question

Comment: to make this clear: if there is one occurance of either 'dog' or 'cat' in one of those hrefs you want to change the target, regardless of anything else right?

Comment: that is exactly right - and friends I apologize that I didn't communicate that correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a regular expression instead ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/gokymuj7/1/)):

```
$(function () {
    var mtarget = $('#jqwlclink'); //the target link that will change only if dog or cat exist for mlink element.

    var dogCatRegexp = /(dog|cat)/i;

    if (mtarget.length) {
        $("#profile-bottom .pleft .mlink").each(function () {
            var txt = $(this).text();
            if (!dogCatRegexp.test(txt)) {
                mtarget.attr("href", "http://different-page/");
            }
        });
    }
});
```